# Pearson correlation p-values plot which method better adjusted my p-values BH or BY? help me understand

Tags: r, plot, correlation, p-value, pearson-correlation

I'm working on DEG dataset and I've done Pearson correlation to prepare my dataset for downstream analysis (co-expression network), so this isn't an exploration phase. When I do pearson on R using Hmisc I get P and R values. I'm trying to use these p-values to make sure that the correlation value r is significant, but since I don't know anyway to correct for pearson bias, I went with p.adjust.

I will attach 3 images 1 for the native p-values, BY-adjusted p.values, and BH-adjusted p.values. Looking at BH and native, I don't think BH adjusted anything, the curve is still showing perfect gradual decrease from 1 to 0, there are no adjusted p.values. While with BY, there is a noticeable new curve at 1 showing the adjusted values that were probably considered significant earlier.

The reason why I originally wanted to go with BY is because it assumes that the two correlated variables regulate or dependent on each other, which fits this biological concept.

Is my reasoning correct?

[pearson native p-values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QExw.png)

[BH-adjusted p-values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QS7e.png)

[BY-adjusted p-values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hko3o.png)

I tried reading about the expected plots for p-values, and other stackoverflow prior questions about this, unfortunately non-exactly addressed my question. I would love to get a more tailored response to my case in this question.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi SiefElDin, welcome to SO. The reason you haven't found an answer to your question is your question isn't a fit for this site. SO is for coding and programming questions.. When a question contains things like " I don't know anyway to correct for pearson bias" and "Is my reasoning correct?", this suggests you are better to put this question to the helpful folk over at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Thanks